# Regex, match group but capture only a specific set

Tags: regex

I want to know if it is possible to capture only the visible chars in my group. it should match CR LF and TAB but not capture it. ATM i'm replacing this chars in the result, but that feels wrong.

```
\Wobjectname\W*?\.\W*?([A-Za-z0-9<>., \t\r\n]+?)\(
```

Comment: No, replacing is the right way after matching as you cannot match discontinuous text within 1 regex match operation.

Comment: I was worried about this answer. I reached the end of regex possibilities the first time in history.